# How to parse INI style file

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a file in format similar to ini

```
[NAME1]
valu1

[NAME2]
value2

[SECTION]
[NAME3]
valu3
```

How do I parse such files in python

Comment: `configparser`. Google it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), documentation description:

> This module defines the class ConfigParser. The ConfigParser class implements a basic configuration file parser language which provides a structure similar to what you would find on Microsoft Windows INI files. You can use this to write Python programs which can be customized by end users easily.

Comment: I tried ConfigParser using SafeConfig parser. The option which appears to me to use the code base of ConfigParser and rewrite a custom parser. If any one know how to do it without rewrite that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The file which i need to parse is not exactly in ini format as it does not contain value pair. I am trying to do this. It also contains data after section tag in more than one lines.

```
with open(filename,'r') as fileObject:
    for line in fileObject:
        doSomething(line)
        # Read subsequent lines
        readFlag = True
        dataLine = ""
        while readFlag:               
            dataLine += fileObject.next()
            # Store the line position
            last_pos = fileObject.tell()
            # Check we got a [code: message]
            if checkTag():
                # We need to break and reset file pointer to last line read
                readFlag = False
                fileObject.seek(last_pos)
```

I m not sure this is the best way to do it.

Comment: It may be best to edit your question with the above to add more context to the question