# Parse a file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, parsing

I have file with below text.

```
[head1]
text1=resp1
text2=resp2
[head2]
text3=resp3
text4=resp4
text5=resp5
```

and so on....

I want to parse this file into dictionary as below.

`dicts={ head1:{text1:resp1, text2:resp2} head2:{text3:resp3, text4:resp4, text5:resp5} }`

Can we parse above file to below dictionary in python? Please provide the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse INI style file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445932/how-to-parse-ini-style-file)

Comment: No, Since only top layer is INI style. Second row is seperated by equals.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good news for you - tomllib which can parse toml files is now part of python's stdlib! https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html

Comment: @rocky You should look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) pointed to by the answer I mentioned.